# php - if a is lower or equal to b and a is greater than 540

Tags: php

how to write this:

if - `$w` is lower **or** equal to `$h`
**and** - `$w` is greater than `540` - do something

here is my try
in both cases I'm getting error `500`

```
if($w =< $h && $w > 540){
  // do something
}

if($w <= $h && $w > 540){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: 2nd variant is correct, having 500 in this case just means that you have another problem somewhere else

Comment: Did you look in the Error Logs for the reason for the crash

Comment: @RiggsFolly - error_log is empty

Comment: Did you check the Apache error log also

Comment: @RiggsFolly - error_log on my server's root folder - that's it - I don't know if any other error_log exists

Comment: If no error log then change php.ini to display all errors at all level.